# TypeError -Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-5-a1dba3055d4c> in <module>

Tags: python, if-statement, integer

I have this code

```
size =4 
@lru_cache
def get_min(size):
 if (size == 4):
        a=2
        return a
    elif size == 5:
        a=3
        return a
    elif size == 6:
        a=4
        return a
    elif size == 7:
        a=5
        return a
    elif size == 8:
        a=5
        return a
    else:
        return a




def evaluate(sbox):
    result = 0
    
    branch = 0
    if BRANCH_WEIGHT > 0:
        branch = calculate(sbox)
        branch = scale(branch, get_min(size), get_max(size))
    result += BRANCH_WEIGHT * branch
return result
```

I want to return a to another function based on the size but i got this error ? could you please help me ...

I am not sure what is the error ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full traceback.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

#### The `else` is returning a non-existent variable

Did you intend to return `size` instead of `a` at that point?